# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS crashes on Lenovo ThinkPad T590

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, laptop, lenovo

I have a new Lenovo ThinkPad T590 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It works quite good, but I also experience system crashes. Maybe the hardware is too new.

Here's the syslog of one crash
[image]

Furthermore there are cases where a keyboard key get stuck (i.e. iiiiiiii). If that happens the only solution is a reboot.

Futher investigations of the syslog show lots of wifi-errors. I.e.:

```
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  505.841836] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  505.943955] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  505.943967] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.148656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.148678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.148853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:49 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.353282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.558045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.967749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  506.967771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  507.070040] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  507.173199] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  507.173222] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
Jul  1 17:42:50 tou1120n03 kernel: [  507.173230] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707:wq
```

Do you have any hints, how I could solve my issues? Do you think an upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 could be a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install and run the [LTS hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) when using Ubuntu LTS on a desktop/laptop system.

In this case, the issue with Intel wireless is a bug in the older kernel shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and is fixed in later kernels.

Install the HWE kernel (and Xorg) and reboot into it.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed the HWE kernel. I will test it and report back, if that solves my issues. If so, you saved my day!! :)

Comment: Now my Ubuntu 18.04 works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @wuarmin hello! Is integreted camera work fine on your T590 with Ubuntu?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs yes my integrated cam works as expected